# MS Word randomly adds white space before a new line begins

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

Image of issue:
[image: Image of issue]

In my word document that has had no issues until now, the 470th page has randomly begun adding a blank space that I cannot get rid of. No page formatting or font size changing has altered it. It only starts on the second line of a paragraph. This continues being the case for the 471st page, but going back to the 469th and adding a new paragraph, the text works perfectly fine. I don't have a clue why this begun happening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: (After you accepted, I found that there is a shortcut for setting hanging indents; if you inadvertently pressed `Ctrl`+`T`, it sets a hanging indent of 0.5 inch for each press within a paragraph. This might have happened accidentally while reaching for `Shift` +`T`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your paragraph formats - this looks like you managed to get a “hanging indent” set. If this is what’s happened, you’ll see that for the paragraph, the left indent is set to some amount, and the first line is set to that same amount, but negative.

(After you accepted, I found that there is a shortcut for setting hanging indents; if you inadvertently pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, it sets a hanging indent of 0.5 inch for each press within a paragraph. This might have happened accidentally while reaching for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.)